# How can we achieve audio passthourgh in Chromecast Styled Media Receiver

Tags: android, chromecast

We're trying to play 5.1 audio on Chrome-cast Player via Audio Passthrough from Android app. But we get only 2.1 as audio output.

Even when we ingested only 5.1 audio, we have received below error,

```
[cast.player.hls.PackedAudioParser] Neither ID3 nor ADTS header was found at 0 
[cast.player.api.Host] error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.NETWORK/315
```

[image]

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media#audio_passthrough

Encoding tool used: **ffmpeg**

Input Params:

- Url: http://cdn.example.com/video.m3u8
- MimeType: application/x-mpegURL
- Audio codec: ac-3

Sample m3u8 file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio/6ch",LANGUAGE="tam",NAME="Tamil",CHANNELS="6",URI="https://cdn.example.com/videos/audio_video_seperation/audio_5.1/master.m3u8""

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio/mp4a/2ch",LANGUAGE="tam",NAME="Tamil",CHANNELS="2",URI="https://cdn.example.com/videos/video_audio_seperation/audio_2.1/master.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AUDIO="audio/6ch",BANDWIDTH=1045504,AUTOSELECT=YES,CODECS="avc1.4D401F,ac-3",RESOLUTION=853x480,FRAME-RATE=25.000
https://cdn.example.com/videos/video_audio_seperation/video_480/master.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,AUDIO="audio/mp4a/2ch",SUBTITLES="subs",BANDWIDTH=1044480,CODECS="avc1.4D401F,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=853x480,FRAME-RATE=25.000
https://cdn.example.com/videos/video_audio_seperation/video_480/master.m3u8
```

Chromecast debug messages:

- Device supports ac-3 encoding
  [image]

Queries:

1. Is there any sample media file available to test 5.1 audio on chrome-cast?
2. Which is right way to decouple audio and video stream from source mp4 file for HLS?

- Any sample ffmpeg command is useful

3. How to fix or check ADTS header issue on audio file?